# How to scroll up the selected item

Tags: android

My application have Linear Layouts. how to scroll up the selected Linear Layout? it means suppose application have 5 linear layouts. if i selected 3rd Linear layout then it will be top(means Starting) of the screen and at that time first 2 linear layouts are above the 3rd Linear Layout, 4th and 5th Linear Layouts are below the 3rd Linear layout.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these [ViewGroup methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html):

```
public void removeViewAt (int index)  Since: API Level 1

public void addView (View child, int index)  Since: API Level 1
```

Having said that, you may want to consider using a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead of a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about not being able to see them in the editor? Or that you can't get to it on the handset?

If you can't see it in the xml editor viewer then you need to choose a larger simulated screen size so that it shows more of your app. That is only a temporary solution if you just want to see how things will look without compiling.

If you can't see the layouts on the handset, it is because they are taking up more vertical space than your handset has (obviously). The best way, in my opinion, to fix that is to add [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to your main.xml. `ScrollView` can only have one child so what you want to do is put a `LinearLayout` within your `ScrollView` and put everything else in that as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                ...
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                ...
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout3"
                ...
        </LinearLayout>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: or yeah as per @Aleadam, you could also do a `ListView` if you have a lot of simple items, to me, it seems that if you have a few more complicated items then `ScrollView` is better, but i could be wrong.